# How to display binary MQTT data?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using the Mosquitto command `mosquitto_sub` to display data from an MQTT server:

```
mosquitto_sub -t "#" -v
```

The messages I want to display contains binary data, which Mosquitto tries to display as text.

Is there any way to display the MQTT messages in a better way for binary data? For example as the hex-values of the bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mosquitto_sub` man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html#outputformat) has a section called "Output format" which covers this.

You can use the `-F` option to specify a formatting string.

e.g.

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t '#' -F %X
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the output of the `--help` flag but I didn't check the manual. Sloppy.

Comment: It turns out my target system uses mosquitto_sub 1.4.15 which does not have the `-F` option. That's why I didn't find it in the help text. Sigh...