# What is the format for mosquitto_sub to display spaces between bytes in a binary message?

Tags: formatting, mqtt, mosquitto

This option produces no spacing between bytes in a binary message:

```
paul@desktop:~$ mosquitto_sub -t out -F '%x' -v
3031320033340035
3031320033340035
```

I hoped this would work:

```
paul@desktop:~$ mosquitto_sub -t out -F '%3x'
 30
 30
```

but it truncates the message. What is a solution to get some separation between the bytes, e.g. `30 31 32 00 33 34 00 35`?

BTW, I've read https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html#outputformat and [How to display binary MQTT data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060893/how-to-display-binary-mqtt-data).

Comment: Just out of interest what version of mosquitto_sub are you using (it's in the first line of `mosquitto_sub --help`)? I can't get your second example to work with 2.0.18.

Comment: @hardillb `mosquitto_sub version 2.0.14 running on libmosquitto 2.0.14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible within mosquitto_sub, however it can be done with a sed command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t \$SYS/broker/uptime -F %x | sed 's/\(..\)/\1 /g'
```

Having said that, the `precision` format option is currently unused for hex payloads, so adding support for `mosquitto_sub -F %.4x ...` seems like a good idea. That'll be in the next (long overdue) feature version.

For example:

```
$ mosquitto_sub -F %.4x ...
3733 3238 3738 2073 6563 6f6e 6473
```